# Using :last-child and :first-child with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write my first self-built jQuery script, as a super simple gallery.

CSS:

```
#gallery li{
        display:none;
    }

    #gallery li.current {
        display: block;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <li class="current"><img src="img/1.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/2.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/3.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/4.jpg" /></li>
</div>
<div id="controls">
    <span id="left">&#60;</span>
    <span id="right">&#62;</span>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){
    $('#controls #left').click(function(){
        var old = $('li.current');
        $('li.current').removeClass('current');
        if (old = $('#gallery:first-child')){
            $('#gallery:last-child').addClass('current');
        }else{
        $(old).prev('li').addClass('current');
        }
    });
    $('#controls #right').click(function(){
        var old = $('li.current');
        if (old = $('#gallery:last-child')){
            $('#gallery:first-child').addClass('current');
        }else{
        $('li.current').removeClass('current');
        $(old).next('li').addClass('current');
        }
    });
});
```

It worked fine until I added the if/else statements to check whether we're looking at the first/last gallery image. I want this statement so that the gallery loops. Can't figure out why it's not working, and debug is giving me nothing.

Can I get a little push in the right direction?

EDIT: using some suggestions below, here's where I'm at:

```
$(function(){
    $('#left').click(function(){
        var old = $('li.current');
        old.removeClass('current');
        if (old == $('#gallery li:first-child')){
            $('#gallery li:last-child').addClass('current');
        }else{
        old.prev('li').addClass('current');
        }
    });
    $('#right').click(function(){
        var old = $('li.current');
        old.removeClass('current');
        if (old == $('#gallery li:last-child')){
            $('#gallery li:first-child').addClass('current');
        }else{      
        old.next('li').addClass('current');
        }
    });
});
```

Still isn't looping around though (pressing "left" on the first image makes the gallery blank, as does pressing "right" on the last image)

Comment: `old = $('#gallery:last-child')` should be `old == $('#gallery:last-child')`

Comment: Ah, stupid error on my part. However, even with this included it's not working.

Comment: What doesn't work ? What's the expected ?

Comment: @RicardoLohmann wrong, you can't use `==` on objects.

Comment: @jack `old[0] == $('#gallery:last-child')[0]` fixes it.

Comment: New quick question - why are you putting `<li>` in a `<div>`. That's not valid HTML

Comment: @Ian because I am absolutely new at this and prone to simple errors. Thanks for letting me know! (You're just saying I need to wrap the `<li>`s in a `<ul>`, correct?)

Comment: @RicardoLohmann Yeah, I forgot to mention that comparing two jQuery collections doesn't work; individual objects can be compared for equality (basically, them being the same object rather than having the same contents).

Comment: @Jascination Technically, yeah. But it will style it differently (maybe). I'm not sure what nested `li` elements in a `div` look like. Anyways, that's most likely what you are looking for, but you are obviously welcome to change the styling of any element you end up using to make it look the way you want. You may want all `div`s but maybe there's something else you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.is(':first-child)` and `.is(':last-child')` to find out if something is the first or last child respectively:

```
$('#controls #left').click(function() {
    var old = $('li.current')
        .removeClass('current');

    if (old.is(':first-child')) {
        // search the siblings for the last child
        old.siblings(':last-child').addClass('current');
    } else {
        $(old).prev('li').addClass('current');
    }
});

$('#controls #right').click(function() {
    var old = $('li.current')
        .removeClass('current');

    if (old.is(':last-child')) {
        old.siblings(':first-child').addClass('current');
    } else {
        $(old).next('li').addClass('current');
    }
});
```

​
Btw, I would change your HTML to this:

```
<div id="controls">
    <span class="left">&#60;</span>
    <span class="right">&#62;</span>
</div>
```

And then use `$('#controls .left')` and `$('#controls .right')` to target your clickable elements.

**Edit**

A fancier approach could be this, food for thought:

```
// wrap the functionality inside an anonymous function
// localizing the gallery and controls blocks
(function($gallery, $controls) {
    var pos = 0;

    // this function performs the actual move left and right, based on event data being passed in via evt.data.delta
    function move(evt) {
        var $items = $gallery.children(), // if the gallery never changes size you should cache this value
        max = $items.length;

        $items.eq(pos).removeClass('current');
        pos = (pos + evt.data.delta) % max; // update the position
        $items.eq(pos).addClass('current');
    }

    // attach the controls
    $controls
        .on('click', '.left', {
            delta: -1 // left decreases the position
        }, move)
        .on('click', '.right', {
            delta: 1 // right increases the position
        }, move);

    // make sure the first is always selected
    $gallery.children().removeClass('current').eq(pos).addClass('current');

}($('#gallery'), $('#controls')));​​​​​​​​​ // immediate invocation
```

Comment: This one got it working, and seems like the best way to achieve the intended result with minimal code. As an absolute beginner to JS/jquery, glad to learn a better way to do it, cheers.

Comment: Although you are wrong that you can't compare objects. You can easily compare `old[0] == $('#gallery:first-child')[0]`. Not preferable, but...

Comment: @Ian I didn't say you couldn't ... you couldn't *like that*; of course, comparing two DOM elements would work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to be using `==`:

```
if (old == $('#gallery:first-child')){
```

and

```
if (old == $('#gallery:last-child')){
```

Although that won't work anyways, as pointed out by **Jack**, because they are separate jQuery calls that may select the same elements and return similar jQuery objects, but won't work with comparison because they are separate collections of DOM element(s). The correct way is to use `.is` like I provide below...**or** to compare with:

```
if (old[0] == $('#gallery:first-child')[0]){
```

Indexing them like that retrieves the first item each in the selected sets, which are the actual DOM elements, and can be compared. Probably not preferred, but its not wrong.

Here's an example of proving this is true: http://jsfiddle.net/4adSj/

You're also doing a few weird things. You don't need to use this selector: `$('#controls #right')` - `$('#right')` is unique enough thanks to how `id` should be used.

Also, you store `var old = $('li.current');` and then the next line you don't bother using `old` - you re-get it like `$('li.current')`.

Also, you are nesting `<li>` elements in a `<div>`, when they should only be nested in `<ul>`, `<ol>`, or `<menu>`.

One more - the variable `old` is a jQuery object, so you don't need to be doing `$(old)` every other time you want to access it after you declared it. Just use `old.jQueryMethod()`.

Finally, the other problem is that your selector for the `if` statements:

```
$('#gallery:last-child')
```

Means find the element that has the `id` "gallery" and is a last-child. You probably want:

```
$('#gallery > li:last-child')
```

Which means find the child element that is the last `li` child element of the parent element with an `id` of "gallery".

So here's my suggestion of your final code to use:

```
$(function(){
    $('#left').on("click", function () {
        var old = $('li.current');
        old.removeClass('current');
        if (old.is(':first-child')){
            $('#gallery > li:last-child').addClass('current');
        } else {
            old.prev('li').addClass('current');
        }
    });

    $('#right').on("click", function () {
        var old = $('li.current');
        old.removeClass('current');
        if (old.is(':last-child')){
            $('#gallery > li:first-child').addClass('current');
        } else {
            old.next('li').addClass('current');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Did that as per Ricardo's suggestion above, but it's still not working (code goes left/right now, but doesn't loop around like it should do)

Comment: @Jascination Look at my update. I think it's the condition you're using for your `if` statement

Comment: That's where I got to, minus the `#gallery > li:first-child`. Can you briefly explain what the difference is between that and `#gallery li:first-child`?

Comment: -1. You can't compare objects with `==` like that. It will always be `false`

Comment: Considering it isn't looping around still (with your edits), this may be correct.

Comment: @Jack Can't believe I forgot that. I was so wrapped up in using what the OP had and listening to Ricardo. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: it worked with me when add space before last-child $('#aside_menul :last-child') last child link

Answer (score 0):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ukemis/4/edit)**

```
var c = 0; 
var imgN = $('#gallery li').length; // 4   
$('#left, #right').click(function(){
  c = this.id=='right' ? ++c : --c ;
  $('#gallery li').hide().eq( c%imgN ).show(); 
});
```

Or even:

```
var c = 0; 
$('#left, #right').click(function(){
  $('#gallery li').hide().eq( (this.id=='right'?++c:--c) % 4 ).show(); 
});
```

**[gallery Demo](http://jsbin.com/ukemis/5/edit)**

P.S: instead of `.hide()` you can use `.removeClass('current')`
and instead of `.show()` you can use `.addClass('current')`